# Lumen - Middleware sendo executado em todas as requisições

Tags: php, laravel, route, lumen, middleware

Criei um `Middleware` que está funcionando perfeitamente, porém ele está sendo executado em rotas que declarei no grupo de rotas e também está sendo executado em outras rotas das quais não declarei.

***Exemplo***:

---

*Rota 1:*

```
$router->post('/xpto', 'Controller@xpto');
```

*Rota 2:*

```
$router->group(['middleware' => 'meuMiddleware'], function () use ($router) {
   $router->post('/xpto2', 'Controller@xpto2');
});
```

Ambas as rotas do exemplo estão chamando o `Middleware`.

Comment: Onde está definida a primeira rota? Como comprovou que o middleware está sendo executado nela?

Comment: Coloque o seu **App\Kernel.php** aqui. Se você colocou a classe deste Middleware no array `$middleware`, ele irá ser executado em todas as rotas.

Comment: Perfeito, alterei o registro do Middleware e funcionou. Obrigado